# Difference between @Named and @Qualifier annotation in CDI?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

Difference between @Named and @Qualifier annotation in CDI? 
When do we use what

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is javax.inject.Named annotation supposed to be used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415261/what-is-javax-inject-named-annotation-supposed-to-be-used-for)

Answer (score 3):

`@Named` is an instance of a `@Qualifier` which assigns a specific name to a bean.  That name has to be unique across all beans, regardless of type.

`@Qualifier` as a concept is a way of having multiple beans of the same type that are differentiated based on the various `@Qualifier` annotations they have.

Comment: So why do we use qualifer. We can use @Named annotation to call multiple beans of the same type that are differentiated