# Is there a way to use javax.inject annotations to choose what to inject into constructor within another injection?

Tags: java, inject, javax

Say I have custom type annotations *@Classic* and *@Custom* and I have annotated classes *BarClassic* and *BarCustom* which both implement interface *Bar*.

Then say I have another class *BarUser* where Bar is injected in constructor.

```
public class BarUser {

    @Inject
    private BarUser (Bar bar) {
        ...
    }
```

And a class Foo where I would like to inject *BarUser*, but would like to specify to use say *BarClassic* within the injected *BarUser*.

Is there a way to this with annotations. So what I would like is:

```
public class Foo {

    @Inject
    @Classic
    private BarUser barUser;

    ....
```

And with this I want to specify that the Bar injected within the *BarUser* should be the *@Classic* one. And maybe in another class do:

```
public class DifferentFoo {

    @Inject
    @Custom
    private BarUser barUser;

    ....
```

Is the only way to this to have two different *BarUser* classes as well or is there some magic I could use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415261/what-is-javax-inject-named-annotation-supposed-to-be-used-for

Comment: That would work if I had two different BarUser classes, I am aware. I would like to find out if there is a way to do this without the additional class.