# Dagger: Accessing item created two levels deep in a subcomponent

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have a subcomponent that I need to pull something out of:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = {SubModule.class})
@SubScope
public interface SubComp {
  // ...
  Thing getThing();
}
```

Each time `#getThing`  is called, I need a new instance of `Thing`.

`Thing` also has its own orbit of items that need to be created with it. Naturally, my instinct is to create another subcomponent for it:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = {ModuleThing.class})
@ThingScope
public interface SubCompThing {
  // ...
}
```

But here is my dilemma: Which piece of code should actually be creating `Thing`?

If I put a provider into `SubModule`, I then need to bind that instance into `SubCompThing`, but I get a warning about binding multiple instances. The warning is fatal in my build, and actually states that the warning will become an error in the future:

```
@Module(subcomponents = {SubCompThing.class})
interface SubModule {
   @Provides
   static providesThing(SubCompThing.Factory thingCompFactory) {
     Thing thing = new Thing();
     thingComp = thingCompFactory.create(thing);  // Warning about duplicate binding.
     // Do some stuff with thingComp
     return thing;
   }
}
```

If I have `SubCompThing` create `Thing` directly itself, my warning turns into an error with the same problem:

```
@Module
interface ModuleThing {
    @Provides
    @ThingScope
    static Thing providesThing() {
      return new Thing();
    }
}

@Module(subcomponents = {SubCompThing.class})
interface SubModule {
   @Provides
   static Thing providesThing(SubCompThing.Factory thingCompFactory) {
     thingComp = thingCompFactory.create();
     // Do some stuff with thingComp
     return thingComp.getThing();
   }
}
```

(Dagger compiles that `Thing` is bound twice, since there are two providers for it.)

How can I have my top level `SubComp` return new `Thing`s on demand, and have each of those `Thing`s have their own subcomponent instance associated with them?

Comment: What you've described is very close to Dagger's official documentation on [subcomponents for encapsulation](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/subcomponents.html#subcomponents-for-encapsulation). Your naming makes it a little hard to follow; am I right to understand that a root component (absent) includes a module (absent) referring to SubComp (@SubScope, shown), then SubComp installs SubModule (shown), which refers to SubCompThing (@ThingScope, shown), which installs ModuleThing, which actually instantiates a @ThingScope Thing, right? Does it help to annotate SubModule.providesThing with @SubScope?

Comment: Yup, you've got the gist of it. `SubComp` lives inside of a parent component somewhere. `SubModule#providesThing` is _not_ annotated with the scope, as I need multiple `Thing`s out of the `SubComp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to use a [qualifier annotation](https://dagger.dev/semantics/#keys).

The root of the problem here is that subcomponents inherit bindings from their parent components, so within your deepest subcomponent SubCompThing your exposed Thing binding on your component might very well be injecting the Thing binding that you're installing in SubComp's SubModule...because Dagger doesn't know that your @Provides method in SubModule is itself about to call SubCompThing's `getThing()` method!

As we discussed in the comments, what you're describing is very much like Dagger's official documentation on [subcomponents for encapsulation](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/subcomponents.html#subcomponents-for-encapsulation), which sneakily depicts but does not describe its reliance on a qualifier annotation:

```java
@Subcomponent(modules = DatabaseImplModule.class)
interface DatabaseComponent {
  @PrivateToDatabase Database database();
  /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
}
```

That's the disambiguating trick: Your ModuleThing should bind `@Provides static @PrivateThing Thing`, and your SubCompThing should expose `@PrivateThing Thing getThing()` such that the only bound unqualified Thing is bound in your SubModule. (Incidentally, this would allow you to inject a Thing in SubCompThing, delegating to SubModule's implementation to create a brand new SubCompThing instance from within ModuleThing's call stack.)

I've defined a cheap qualifier annotation here, but you're welcome to use [@Named](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5415261/1426891) to prototype it.

```java
@Qualifier @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) public @interface PrivateThing {}

@Module
interface ModuleThing {
  @Provides
  @ThingScope
  @PrivateThing
  static Thing providesThing() {
    return new Thing();
  }
}

@Subcomponent(modules = {ModuleThing.class})
@ThingScope
public interface SubCompThing {
  @PrivateThing getThing();
}
```

At that point, your SubModule will work with no additional modifications, abstracting away the creation of Thing to a black-box implementation of SubCompThing (which I prefer slightly, such that you don't have to bring Thing's instantiation details into SubModule). It also means you can keep Thing scopeless so you can instantiate more than one of them: *When you call the provider, you'll see something new. [That way you can make both `thing1` and `thing2`.](https://images.app.goo.gl/146sU3WeGUaLKWFs5)*